# Rails app for food truck, using twitter to update the google map.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-maps, twitter, geolocation

So I am writing a rails application for my friends food truck business.

The functionality that I am trying to create with this specific application is the ability for him to update the google map by posting a Geo-location tag on twitter.

A lot of the ruby gems that deal with google maps seem to be depreciated so I'm a bit lost at the moment.  If anyone could just point me in the correct direction I would appreciate it.

I realize that this feature is just a quality of life feature but id like to be able to do it with embedded ruby and not have to break out the JavaScript (ugh).    Ideal this kind of automation would be great for this particular type of website because my friend won't always have access to the back-end of the website when he is on the move. (Already able to update a map from an admin backend but its not good enough for a business that moves multiple places in a given day.)

anyways, thanks in advance.  (if anyone wants me to post any of my code I will.)

Comment: I don't think that you need a gem for this. Do you know how to add a simple google map to a view without any gem?

Comment: @bTazi is right, you probably don't need a gem for this. Set up your Rails app to periodically (maybe every half hour) retrieve your friend's tweets. Using the latest tweet location, update the map. P.S. Using JS will make this much easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after reading your question, I thought it would be fun to tinker with the Twitter API again since I haven't used it in a while.

I went ahead and created a [sample application](https://github.com/anthonyto/twitter-geotracking-example) for you that basically does what you were asking for. It looks for recent tweets from a user, grabs the latest one, then updates a Google map with a marker on that location.

Keep in mind that this was quickly thrown together, so it's far from perfect. But all the concepts should be there!

Feel free to reach out if you have any questions about the app or anything else. I'm always happy to help.

Comment: I've taken a look at your source.  Does exactly what i wanted... Thanks.